# How to make a template repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive, I want that template to show all the rows from data set

```
app.directive('exampleDirective', [ 'TestProvider', 'TestFactory', function (TestProvider, TestFactory) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<tr><td>{{Name}} </td><td>{{Surname}}</td></tr>',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
       var dat= TestFactory.dataReturn();
       for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {

               scope.Name = dat[i].Name;
               scope.Surname = dat[i].Surname;
           console.log(dat[i]);
       }

       // alert("hah");
    }
};
}]);
```

How can I make it repeat like **ng-repeat** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your service returning a promise. Here is the simple code to repeat your data in table.

```
app.directive('exampleDirective', [ 'TestProvider', 'TestFactory', function (TestProvider, TestFactory) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<table ng-repeat="person  in  persons"><tr><td>{{person.Name  }} </td><td>{{person.Surname}}</td></tr></table>',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
        TestFactory.dataReturn().then(function(resp){
            scope.persons = resp.data;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could redefine your element directive to represent a *single* object, and then ng-repeat the directive itself.  Obviously, this would require moving the location where you use the factory.  Your application architecture may or may not be able to accommodate this change.

directive:

```
app.directive('exampleDirective', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<tr><td>{{person.Name}} </td><td>{{person.Surname}}</td></tr>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            person: '='
        }
    };
}]);
```

And usage:

```
<example-directive ng-repeat="data in dataFromFactory" person="data"></example-directive>
```